# How Can I Get Started With Embedded Programming With the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, embedded, raspberry-pi

I have been given a Raspberry Pi Model A by my school. They want me to investigate it and I really want to get involved with some embedded programming with the raspberry pi. However, I have no idea how I can get started because there seems to be no good online tutorials that i have found so far and I haven't even worked out how to set the Pi up for this sort of programming. I have a fairly good knowledge of python and a very basic understanding of electronics. Please can somebody help me out or give me a link or a tutorial to something?

Thank You Very Much

Comment: a google search for "embedded programming raspberry pi" turns up several tutorials ... but really an Arduino would probably be easier for you...

Comment: This site is really only for questions which can have specific answers.  While http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com nominally has the same rules, you may at least find more interesting reading over there.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I greatly appreciate them!

Answer (score 2):

If using the recommended Raspbian/Debian OS image, the Raspberry Pi is already set up for programming in Python, Scratch, C and C++ among others. Although for C/C++ you would do well to install [Code::Blocks](http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/codeblocks). I think the GPIO libraries are included in the standard distribution also.

A good place to start is perhaps with the introductory articles in [The MagPi](http://www.themagpi.com/); a dedicated on-line magazine that has something of the flavour of old-school computer magazines of the 1980's. It covers all aspects of the Raspberry Pi, but has a number of articles on what RaspberryPi.org insist on calling "physical computing", which I guess covers embedded systems but also control systems in general.  All back issues are available for download.

It is also worth keeping an eye on [www.raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/), there are regular articles on what others are doing with their Raspberry Pi, and many of those people will probably be more than willing to share information and resources.  Also this is the place to get up-to-date OS distros and alternative OS's, and there is a user forum.

Chapters 12 and 13 of the "official" [Raspberry Pi Users Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Guide-Upton-Gareth-Halfacree/dp/B00CB5HEHE/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&qid=1370275372&sr=8-16&keywords=raspberry+pi+user+guide) cover hardware interfacing and add-on boards and hardware.  The book is also a good general guide to getting the RPi up and running, and is very inexpensive (especially in eBook form), as are most other books for the RPi of which there are many.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I'm getting started with my embedded programming and have some really interesting ideas coming to life in the living room!

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has a beginner friendly online learning module for the Raspberry Pi. The learning system is specifically geared toward embedded systems and interfacing. They take you from first boot and configuration and cover topics such as  GPIO, interfacing with servo motors, DC motors, stepper motors, temperature sensors, and power control.

You can find the module here: 
http://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-raspberry-pi